# Play! framework subfolders in the "models" one?

Tags: playframework, models

Assume the following flat models structure *(models folder content)*:

- user.java
- group.java
- log.java
- car.java
- motorbike.java

For clarity purpose, I would like to "classify" those models files into subfolders to get the following:

- general

  - user.java
  - group.java
  - log.java
- vehicules

  - car.java
  - motorbike.java

I tried to create two folders into the genuine "models" one and adapted the package import accordingly i.e. `package models.general;` for instance. I then ran the project, the database is created properly (the tables are generated) but I'm unable to save anything. Is there something I missed ?

Comment: Hi, problem solved! (almost by itself) I did a simple project, created subfolders and everything worked out. I still did not pointed out why it did not worked on my former project but at least it is not related to the fact of creating sub folders (sub packages) into the "models" one. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Just for the info: I was importing a large amount of data, as the import took a long time (no error at all but the db was not affected) I thought nothing happened. Actually everything worked as expected but all the db changes are flushed once the method is done. For example this will never be saved: User u = new User(); u.name = "bob"; u.save(); while(true){}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if that solves the problem, but from what you describe, the correct packages would be `models.general` and `models.vehicules`.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I wrote it wrong in my in my question but it was "models.general;" in my code. I edited it since. This said the problem persists.

Comment: Hi again, I just tried with a "toy case" this morning creating a very simple model class and everything seems to work now i.e. the entry is saved and the database created too. My problem therefore may come from something else not related to the fact of using sub folders and packages (as I thought at first). I will then further investigate and possibly post another question if I really get stuck on something but I consider that question one as solved. Thank you for your support